How can exclude all the documents of a collection from a firestore query?
I am querying users collection and all the documents under users collection has a sub collection namely already_seen_docs. Now is there any direct way that I can use so that when I am querying users collection , I can exclude some document's already_seen_docs sub collection from the query to only show the docs that a particular user hasn't seen yet?
Let me elaborate. I am building a dating app. When a new user joins I am adding that user's data as a document under users collection. When a particular user with id for example user_id_1 wants to see other users who are using the dating app, I am querying the users collection. Since I can't show the same person twice to user_id_1, I am storing the profiles (the documents under users collection) user_id_1 has already seen under a sub collection users(collection)-> user_id_1(document)-> seen_profiles(collection)
Now when user_id_1 opens the app again & want to see other profiles I have to exclude the profile (documents under users collection) that user_id_1 has already seen. That is I have to exclude all the documents of users(collection)-> user_id_1(document)-> seen_profiles(collection) from   result of users(collection) query every time user_id_1 opens the app and want to see other people's profile. Now I want to know how I can do that?
In summary every time I query users collection for a particular user id, I want to exclude all the documents that is stored under users(collection)-> particular_user_id(document)-> seen_profiles(collection). Thanks in advance.
I know that firestore queries are shallow. But still is there any workaround.

I'm finding it hard to understand what you're trying to do. If you could provide a concrete example, in terms of a) the data that's present; b) what your query looks like; c) what the current results are; d) what you want the results to be... that would make it much easier to help you.

Please don't elaborate in comments. Instead, edit your question to be clearer - ideally with the concrete example as requested before. See https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints for suggestions about how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.

I have edited the question. Can you check it now?

There is no way to make Firestore exclude documents from a query that could only be returned by another query.  It's just not part of its query capabilities, and it also would not scale in a way that satisfies Firestore's scaling requirements.
The only way to do this is for collections of any size is to query both collections, then write code to remove the set of documents in seen_profiles from the set of documents in users.
Your only other option is a not-in filter, but that requires that you have the values to exclude in memory first, and works with up to 10 values.

The only way to do this is for collections of any size is to query both collections, then write code to remove the set of documents in seen_profiles from the set of documents in users.
This will not be a good workaround when both users and seen_profiles collection contain thousands of douments.  Also if I try to paginate then an additional problem would arise because all the documents fetched in first page might be already in the seen_profiles collection (hypothetically ) & then I have to run the paginated query again which will increase complexity.

So what can be a good workaround if we consider scaling to thousands? Maintaining a different unseen_profiles collection for each user and then when  new user joins then add that user's document in unseen_profiles  of existing users? What do you think?

I gave the only workaround (not-in queries) and its limitations.  Aside from that, there are no workarounds at scale.  This use case is just not a good fit for the way Firestore works.  Consider using a different database that meets your needs better, but also be prepared to pay more for that since this kind of query requires a lot of memory on the database side.
